# Javascript regex, split string by period unless wrapped in double quotes ""

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to split the following string `const str = '"root.doted"."nested.dots"."array.nested.1"[0]';` to become `['"root.doted"', '"nested.dots"', '"array.nested.1"[0]']` using regular expression and the .split function.
The regex I use does not give me the right result, I use the following
`/(".*?"|[^".\s]+)(?=\s*.|\s*$)/g`.

But the result I get is `["\"root.doted\"", ".\"array.nested.1\"", "\"nested.dots\"", "\"array.nested.1\"", "\"array.nested.1\"[0]"]`.

I'm not sure how to fix the regex to give me the desired result

`['"root.doted"', '"nested.dots"', '"array.nested.1"[0]']`.

Any help please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to add a `+` to `(".*?"|[^".\s]+)` so it combines the consecutive rules(e.g. `"array.nested.1"` and `[0]`) into a single match using [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function.

```
/(".*?"|[^".\s]+)+(?=\s*\.|\s*$)/g
```

```js
const str = '"root.doted"."nested.dots"."array.nested.1"[0]';

const regex = /(".*?"|[^".\s]+)+(?=\s*\.|\s*$)/g;

const result = str.match(regex);

console.log(result);
```